# sleep like function with user input intterupt

Tags: shell, unix

I wanted to do a shell function which countdown to n seconds (10 for exemple) and after that, continue the script.
I tried with the sleep function but it does stop the script entirely.
I want something like when the user input "y" during this countdown, it will stop the countdown and do something particular (much like an "interrupt").
And if the countdown finishes without any user input, the script continues.

Thank you !

**UPDATE* *

@Krzysztof Księżyk That's exactly what i wanted !
One difference, if i want the read return only if "Y" is the input how can i do that ? i already tried with the -d and -a...

Here is my code :

```
label="NTFS"
read -n 1 -t 5 MS
if [ -z "$MS" ]
  then
    echo "You don't input value, default will be taken"
  else
    echo -e "\nYou pressed 'Y' and want change default backup device."
    read -p "Please input label of your secondary backup device: " secondary_label
    label=$secondary_label
fi
echo "the choosen backup device label is $label"
```

Comment: You should post the code you have written. It makes it easier to answer your question, and proof of work goes a long way towards getting help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `read` command, eg.

```
read -n 1 -t 10
```

It will wait up to 10 second just for 1 character.

** UPDATE **

modified solution based on extra info from author

```
CNT=0
while [ $CNT -lt 10 ]; do
    (( CNT++ ))
    read -s -n 1 -t 1 -r KEY
    if [ "$KEY" == 'y' ]; then
        echo 'doing something'
    else
        echo 'doing nothing'
    fi
done
```

Comment: ok please take a look at my answer above (I do not master still well stackoverflow lol). It's same as you describe but only with a defined character (like "y").

Answer (score 0):

If you want an interrupt, you probably want to trap SIGINT:

```
#!/bin/sh

trap : SIGINT
echo begin
for((i=0;i<10;i++)); do printf "$i\r"; sleep 1; done &
wait || kill $!
echo
echo end
```

The script counts to 10, but the timer aborts when the user sends a SIGINT (eg ctrl-C)